# How to track the number of scores a user has input?

Tags: python-3.x, average

I have a test average calculator that has the user input how ever many test scores (in btwn 1-100) they would like. I just need to track the amount of test scores the user has input. How would I implement this?

```
#Welcome Message
print("Welcome to the Test Average Calculator!")
print("Say 'STOP' when you are done with Data Entry")

#Variables
total = 0
total_quiz = 0
inpt = input("Enter score: ")

#User Input
while inpt.upper() != "STOP":
    if int(inpt) <= 100 and int(inpt) > 0:
        total += int(inpt)
        total_quiz += 1
    else:
        print("Invalid Score")
    inpt = input("Enter Score or Stop?: ")

#Display Average
print('The Average score is: ',
      format(average, '.2f'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the variable `total_quiz` which keeps a count of the number of scores, therefore to calculate the average, all you need to do is add `average = total / total_quiz` before you print the result:

```
#Welcome Message
print("Welcome to the Test Average Calculator!")
print("Say 'STOP' when you are done with Data Entry")

#Variables
total = 0
total_quiz = 0

while True:
    inpt = input("Enter score: ")

    if inpt.upper() == "STOP":
        break

    if 0 <= int(inpt) <= 100:
        total += int(inpt)
        total_quiz += 1
    else:
        print("Invalid Score")

average = total / total_quiz

# Display Average
print('The Average score is: ', format(average, '.2f'))
```